# How do I deleted a scene collection without deleting the scences inside that collection

Tags: render-layers, scene, select, viewlayers

Pretty self-explanatory. In the Outliner Window, I have a few scenes. However, all the scenes are under a 'scene collection' and I would like to remove the scene collection from the hierarchy.

Comment: You can't, it's the master collection where all collections in the scene are stored.